# Текстовое поле с выбором из списка в lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

Есть готовая база, в которую вносятся документы в определенные формы. В этой форме есть поле в которое добавляется запись из списка, после чего эта форма добавляется (зарегистрировать) в базу.

Суть в том, что это поле надо сделать текстовым (вместо выбора из списка) - сделано, теперь вносишь запись в это поле и должен добавить (зарегистрировать) документ в базу, но на этом этапе вылазит ошибка о том, что данное поле не заполнено, хотя, повторюсь, в нем есть данные.

Собственно вопрос: как это исправить? Где ковырять? Если в коде, то он ниже:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace, cdoc As NotesDocument
    Set cdoc = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
    If ( cdoc.Form(0) = "edit_master" ) Then cdoc.Form = cdoc.source_form(0)

    Dim sc As Variant, Document As Variant, mxSenders As MixCollection
    Set sc = createServiceControl()
    Set Document = sc.getService( "DocumentManager" ).getDocObject( cdoc )

    Select Case Lcase( cdoc.Form(0))
    Case "doc_og", "doc_exp", "doc_in_ext", "search_exp", "search_in_ext" ,"search_og":
        Set mxSenders = sc.getService( "CorrespondentsManager" ).dialogSelectCorrespondent( False, cdoc.specialization (0) )
        If ( mxSenders.Count = 0 ) Then
            Dim answer As Integer
            answer = Messagebox( "Внешний адресат не выбран. Желаете произвести ввести вручную?", 1 + 32, "" )
            If ( answer = 1 ) Then
                Dim s As New NotesSession
                Dim dlg As New NotesDocument( s.CurrentDatabase )
dlg_point:
                If ( ws.DialogBox( "dlg_senders_handmade", True, True, False, False, False, False, "Ручной ввод данных", dlg, True, False, True )) Then
                    If ( dlg.full_name(0) = "" ) Then Beep : Goto dlg_point
                    cdoc.DocSenders = dlg.full_name(0)
                    cdoc.DocSendersID = CORRESPONDENT_ID_HAND_MADE
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Case Else :  '"doc_ord", "doc_in_int", "doc_out_ext", "doc_out_int":
        Set mxSenders = sc.getService( "StaffManager" ).dialogSelectPerson( True )
    End Select

    If ( mxSenders.Count = 0 ) Then
        Call cdoc.RemoveItem ("DocSenders")
        Call cdoc.RemoveItem ("DocSendersID")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Dim mxVal As New MixCollection, mxID As New MixCollection, mxSpec As New MixCollection
    Dim mxAddreses As New MixCollection
    Forall elm In mxSenders.Array
        Call mxID.Append( elm.id )
        Select Case Lcase( cdoc.Form(0))
        Case "doc_og", "doc_exp", "doc_in_ext":
            Call mxVal.Append( elm.title )
            Call mxSpec.AppendCollection( elm.specializations )
            If cdoc.Form(0) = "doc_og" Then
                Call mxAddreses.Append( elm.legal.full )
            End If
        Case Else:
            Call mxVal.Append( elm.displayName )            
        End Select
    End Forall

    cdoc.DocSenders = mxVal.Array
    cdoc.DocSendersID = mxID.Array

    'If cdoc.Form(0) =  "doc_og"  And mxAddreses.Count > 0 Then     cdoc.replyTo_Address = Join(mxAddreses.Array, Chr(13)) ' bug RR3000007033
    ' Формируем список специализаций
    Select Case Lcase( cdoc.Form(0))
    Case "doc_og", "doc_exp", "doc_in_ext":
        If ( mxSpec.Count = 1 ) Then
            cdoc.specialization = mxSpec.Element(1)
        Elseif ( mxSpec.Count > 1 ) Then
            Dim choiceSpec As Variant
            choiceSpec = ws.Prompt( 4, "", "", mxSpec.Element(1), mxSpec.Array )
            If Not Isempty( choiceSpec ) Then cdoc.specialization = choiceSpec
        End If
    End Select
    Call ws.CurrentDocument.Refresh

End Sub
```

Как я понимаю, сюда надо добавить параметр, который говорит, что возможен ручной ввод данных?!

Comment: вы уверены что это javascript? больше как то на basic смахивает.

Comment: @FLK, дак это он и есть, VBS/BS собственной персоной

Comment: LotusScript, но его нету в метках :(
но так как лотус использует javascriptы то пришлось поставить.

ПыСы:действительно по своей логике он смахивает на basic:)

Answer (score 1):

Сам по себе Lotus Notes не может вам сказать, что какое-то поле у вас не заполнено. Надо искать код проверки заполнения поля. Скорее всего это должно быть на форме в QuerySave или QueryClose. Может быть в самом поле в InputTranslation, InputValidation. Ищите по тексту сообщения. Потом уже разбираться с этим алгоритмом проверки. Приведённый вами код бесполезен, т.к. в нём нет сообщения об ошибке, о которой вы говорите, и тем более непонято о каком именно поле идёт речь. Как сопоставить текст вашего сообщения с кодом? Какое имя у поля?